# How to apply different css to two divs with sames classes within a div?

Tags: css

```
<div class="section-cm director-general-section">
  <h2 class="widget-title section-cm-heading heading--center">Director General</h2>
  <img width="140" height="160" class="image wp-image-183  attachment-full size-full" alt="" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;">
  <div class="textwidget custom-html-widget">Director</div>
  <div class="textwidget custom-html-widget">hello</div>
</div>
```

How can I apply different CSS to `.custom-html-widget` DIV? I am unable to add a unique class to the DIVs.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: <div class="section-cm director-general-section">
                    <h2 class="widget-title section-cm-heading heading--center">Director General</h2><img width="140" height="160"  class="image wp-image-183  attachment-full size-full" alt="" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;"><div class="textwidget custom-html-widget">Director</div><div class="textwidget custom-html-widget">hello</div>                </div>

Comment: Which div do you want to select, the one with the text `Director` or the one with the text `hello`? Have you actually tried anything?

Answer (score 2):

You can try out the following code

```
.custom-html-widget:nth-of-type(1){
 color:red;   
}
```

Now if you've many no of div or li item you can simply use the nth-type rule..

Answer (score 1):

Used `+` selector if your div come one by one

```css
.custom-html-widget {
  color: red;
}

.custom-html-widget + .custom-html-widget {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-cm director-general-section">
     <h2 class="widget-title section-cm-heading heading--center">Director General</h2>
     <img width="140" height="160"  class="image wp-image-183  attachment-full size-full" alt="" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;">
     <div class="textwidget custom-html-widget">
       Director
    </div>
   <div class="textwidget custom-html-widget">hello</div>
</div>
```

or Used `:first-of-type` and `:last-child`

```css
.custom-html-widget:first-of-type  {
  color: red;
}

.custom-html-widget:last-child {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-cm director-general-section">
     <h2 class="widget-title section-cm-heading heading--center">Director General</h2>
     <img width="140" height="160"  class="image wp-image-183  attachment-full size-full" alt="" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;">
     <div class="textwidget custom-html-widget">
       Director
    </div>
   <div class="textwidget custom-html-widget">hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use pseudo-class to do that. for more information you can checkout this document.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child
or you can search on google about pseudo-class in css.

Answer (score 0):

```
div.custom-html-widget:first-child(){}
```

To change property of the first child, otherwise for the second :

```
div.custom-html-widget:nth-child(2){}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child):

```css
.custom-html-widget:nth-child( 3 ) {
  background-color: gold;
}
.custom-html-widget:nth-child( 4 ) {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-cm director-general-section">
  <h2 class="widget-title section-cm-heading heading--center">Director General</h2>
  <img width="140" height="160" class="image wp-image-183  attachment-full size-full" alt="" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;">
  <div class="textwidget custom-html-widget">Director</div>
  <div class="textwidget custom-html-widget">hello</div>
</div>
```

This works by selecting the *third* and *fourth* child element of `.section-cm`.

---

You can use [:nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type):

```css
.custom-html-widget:nth-of-type( 1 ) {
  background-color: red;
}
.custom-html-widget:nth-of-type( 2 ) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-cm director-general-section">
  <h2 class="widget-title section-cm-heading heading--center">Director General</h2>
  <img width="140" height="160" class="image wp-image-183  attachment-full size-full" alt="" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;">
  <div class="textwidget custom-html-widget">Director</div>
  <div class="textwidget custom-html-widget">hello</div>
</div>
```

This works because we're selecting the *first* and *second* instances of the type of element `.custom-html-widget` happens to be, which is a `div`.

---

You can use [:first-of-type()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) and [:last-of-type()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type):

```css
.custom-html-widget:first-of-type {
  background-color: seagreen;
}
.custom-html-widget:last-of-type {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-cm director-general-section">
  <h2 class="widget-title section-cm-heading heading--center">Director General</h2>
  <img width="140" height="160" class="image wp-image-183  attachment-full size-full" alt="" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;">
  <div class="textwidget custom-html-widget">Director</div>
  <div class="textwidget custom-html-widget">hello</div>
</div>
```

This works because there's only two DIVs and you're selecting the first and last ones.

---

There's a few other too like [:last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) and [:nth-last-of-type()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-of-type).